# Powershell - Invoke-Webrequest on every row of a datatable

Tags: powershell

I have working powershell code that gets data from a database, I then loop through the rows, convert the row to Json using `ConvertTo-Json` and then call `Invoke-WebRequest` using the Json body that was created.

I was curious if I could simplify this task?

I know I can do something like this to create JSON out of each row:

```
($UserToUpdate.Tables[0].Rows | select $UserToUpdate.Tables[0].Columns.ColumnName ) | ConvertTo-Json
```

I Was thinking I might be able to do something like

```
($UserToUpdate.Tables[0].Rows | select $UserToUpdate.Tables[0].Columns.ColumnName ) | ConvertTo-Json | Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Method $method -Uri $uri -Body $body
```

However I am not sure how to use the results of the previous `ConvertTo-Json` as the `$body` in the `Invoke-Webrequest`.

I may be barking up the wrong tree, but thought it was worth trying!

Answer (score 1):

The Powershell pipeline passes a full copy of your JSON Object through to `Invoke-WebRequest`, but `Invoke-WebRequest` doesn't know how to deal with it by default.

the easiest thing to do is pipe it into a `Foreach-Object`, (aliases of `ForEach` or just `%`, any work) and then operate on it from there.

```
... | ConvertTo-Json | Foreach { Invoke-WebRequest -Body $_ -Uri $Uri }
```

the piped object (in this case your JSON string) will be represented by the `$_` variable within the `{}` scriptblock after the `Foreach`

hopefully that helps you get this working.